# What is ABSTRACT in AWT

Tags: java

Can some one please explain me what is the Abstract means in Abstract Window Toolkit?

Is it related to Abstract (incomplete definition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Jean Sebastien in [his forum post here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343687/GUI/java/AWT-abstract):

> It is an abstraction of the underlying system (windows, linux, mac
>   os...) actually displaying the components.
>
> When you use an AWT component, for example a Button, Java uses native
>   libraries to display the button (think of something like
>   "Windows.displayButton(myButton)" or "Linux.displayButton(myButton)").
>
> The underlying system provides the "concrete" implementation for the
>   "abstract" AWT component.

Comment: Plagiarism: copied verbatim from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343687/GUI/java/AWT-abstract)

Answer (score 1):

It is abstract in that it has a level of abstraction over the underlying native user-interface. For example, creating an AWT check box would cause AWT directly to call the underlying native subroutine that created a check box.

It is "incomplete" in so far as the user does not need to create components on the native level OS using calls such as [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows Platforms for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to Abstract (incomplete definition). It is Abstract in the sense it is not related to OS or a specific windowing system.

Comment: I'm quite sure, since this is something that I've heard more than once in more than a few java courses and trainings I attended. However, I must admit that in a quick search I couldn't find it on the web.I